# global exception handler not working in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

In case of exception, the request is not ending as the error handler is not called. The console is showing the error but my message 'internal server error' is not send as
response. The error block is not entering inside the global handler.

```
const createError = require('http-errors');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cors = require('cors');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const rulesRouter = require('./routes/rules');
const lambdasRouter = require('./routes/lambda');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express['static'](path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.use('/api', rulesRouter);
app.use('/lambda', lambdasRouter);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send({
    'api_error': {
      'dev_msg': 'Resource not available : Not Found',
      'user_msg': 'Resource not available',
      'user_msg_title': 'Not found!',
      'code': 404,
    },
  });
});

//error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500).send('interal server error');
});



module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Can you add the part of code, which shows how are you handling the errors in the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you show us how you sent the error ?

We usually do

```
try {

    throw new Error('New error');

} catch(error) {
    next(error)
}
```

This is next(error) that sends the error to the next error handling middleware